# SQL Server query returning results that are outside of a between statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL Server query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MachineEvents
WHERE DepartmentId = @DepartmentId 
  AND EvenStart BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime
```

The table has several columns, but the columns with parameters are of the following types:

- `DepartmentId nvarchar(4)`
- `EventStart datetimeoffset(7)`

Occasionally when this query is run, I get some results that are outside of the parameters. For example I ran the query with the below parameters this morning:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MachineEvents
WHERE DepartmentId = 'W15' 
  AND EventStart BETWEEN '07/22/2022 9:00:00 AM -04:00' AND '07/22/2022 10:00:00 AM -04:00'
```

However, I got a few results with the following `EventStart` times:

- 07/22/2022 05:34:00 -04:00
- 07/22/2022 06:40:54 -04:00
- 07/22/2022 07:46:02 -04:00

If I run the identical query, but between 07/21/2022 9:00:00 PM -04:00 and 07/22/2022 9:00:00 AM -04:00, all of the results I get return the expected values, with no outliers. Any ideas what I did wrong here?

All the times in the table are in the same timezone. This is strictly a locally used and run database for internal purposes. I've read through https://sqlblog.org/dates, which was a great read, but his thoughts on BETWEEN statements don't seem to apply here from what I can see.

Thanks!

Comment: What data type is the `EventStart` column? Does it even have a time zone? Or is that just added by whatever converts the values to textual representation?

Comment: How are your start and end time parameters declared? WHat happens if you replace the parameters with the actual values you show in your query?

Comment: EventStart is a DateTimeOffset. I get the same results if I just hard type in the query with the values in SSMS

Comment: I can't replicate your problem (using unambiguous date formats, as there aren't 22 months in a year): [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=fefb3e06886ead55d87f442c12168724)

Comment: As an aside, there is good reason to [avoid `BETWEEN` for queries involving dates and times](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), although it shouldn't be the cause of the problems here.

Comment: Might be a corrupted index, try `DBCC CHECKDB`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback folks - turns out the issue was some mismatched data coming from the application that was putting the data in the database, and the offsets weren't being saved correctly.